# How to control order of execution of workflow rules on same object

Tags: apex, workflow, order-of-execution

I have two workflow rules which says:

```
First Workflow rule : Copy A's value to B .

Second Workflow rule: Coyp B's value to C.
```

I am finding issue with order of execution of above workflow rules, sometime Second is firing before First and copying old values. So i ended up have different value from B and C at end.
Users Enter sometimes values in A and SomeTimes value in B.

Since both are field updates putting them both in one workflow rule will not make sense as field updates would also be in random order. Client don't want to go with trigger approach.

Comment: Why not just put into one wfr and with two field updates copy A to b and a to c? Seems a needs to go both into b an c buy your question. If entry is a problem use two wfr one with a condition a is blank and the other where a is not blank

Comment: Are A and B the same SObjectType? and if not, in what way are they related?

Comment: Why don't you add a condition in or `ISCHANGED(A)` in second WF.

Answer (score 2):

Since it's difficult to put order of execution of workflows. I have encountered similar use case in my project.

So, First Copy A's value to B - perform by workflow.

and then Copy B's value to C - perform by process builder.

Since, workflow rule fires first, followed by process builder. Refer [Triggers and Order of Execution](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm)